# I am setting up an architecture for multiple projects on Linux. Different clients. Any advice?

Tags: linux, cluster, architecture, infrastructure

This will probably be on cloud.

Can anyone give any general tips on setting up a Admin-server/DB/Web/Processing/Development-environment architecture?

Like...

- Security, only 1 admin server can be
  SSH'ed into. The others are ip-table
  blocked.
- Admin server can SSH into other
  servers with a key.

Anyone have tips like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a bit general for me.  But on the specific thing you said:

```
 - Security, only 1 admin server can be SSH'ed into. The others are ip-table
   blocked.
 - Admin server can SSH into other servers with a key.
```

The problem is that you have a single point of a failure for being able to administer all your servers, so I would set up at least two servers that you can ssh into if you feel the need to limit ssh to most of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Hire someone who knows what they're doing to set all this up.